# How to get the second string?

Tags: php

I'd like to get the 2nd string/LIVE video from here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRZP4zH-4yPgjzjTsoQp2Eg

With this PHP I can get the first string/video:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{$string = " " . $string;
$ini = strpos($string, $start);
if ($ini == 0) return "";
$ini+= strlen($start);
$len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
return substr($string, $ini, $len);}

$url = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRZP4zH-4yPgjzjTsoQp2Eg');
$url = get_string_between($url, 'vi/', '/');
header("Location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$url");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you parsed the HTML, take a look at PHP DOM.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: What's the second string?

Comment: Open https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRZP4zH-4yPgjzjTsoQp2Eg... view the source code... search for: /vi... I'd like to get the second line

Comment: @PauGuerra [Take a look at the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: The example below seems much simpler, direct and useful than your link that confuses even more. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the offset of strpos to get the second one. I updated these lines:

```
$ini = strpos($string, $start);
if ($ini == 0) return "";
```

To be:

```
$ini1 = strpos($string, $start);
if ($ini1 == 0) return "";
$ini = strpos($string, $start,$ini1+1);
```

All it does is use the offset of the first find to start the second search. In the long term, you would want to use an offset parameter in your function to select the index you want. `get_string_between($string, $start, $end,$offset)`

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It worked perfectly with some url's except this one: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkAGrHCLFmlK3H2kd6isipg
Gets the third line instead the second line. Do you have an idea why?